# How to implement openid providers with Sharepoint?

Tags: 2010, claims, open-source

I need to implement Openid providers with Sharepoint . The implementation would be something similar to Sharepoint.Stackexchange site. The user clicks http://sgdf.com and user should be taken to a page where all the providers are displayed ( gmail,yahoo,openid,twiter,linked etc ) . User enter his loginname and password and enters the site. I want to use a approach where MS can provide support. I see that the DotnetOpenAuth.dll are open source and i donot want to use it.